# How to replace HTML span opening and closing tag that has specific class name with div tag

Tags: javascript, html, regex, regex-group

I have this HTML code

```html
<span class="line"><span>// Before</span></span> 
<span class="line">
  <span>import</span>
<span> </span><span>db</span>
<span> </span><span>from</span><span>    </span>
  <span>'../../lib/db-admin'</span><span>;</span>
</span> 
<span class="line"><span>// After</span></span> 
<span class="line"><span>import</span>
<span> </span><span>db</span><span> </span>
<span>from</span><span> </span>
<span>'lib/db-admin'</span><span>;</span></span>
```

I would like to replace every opening and closing span tag with class="line" with the div tag. How can i do it using regular expressions?

This is what i've already tried, but cannot get it until working condition.

```
/(<span class="line">.*?<\/span>)\s*<span class="line">(.*?)<\/span>((?!<\/span>).)*<\/span>/g, '$1</div><div class="line">$2</div>'
```

Comment: Don't [parse HTML with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/21363224).

Comment: Is there a reason you want to use regular expressions instead of (usually easier, and more straightforward) DOM manipulation?

Comment: I see what you're trying to do. You would like this `<span class="line"> <span>// Before</span></span>`  to become this `<div class="line"> <span>// Before</span></div>` ?

Comment: If that's the case, you'd have to get the nested _`spans`_ to find the closing span that corresponds to the open one with the class you need. This is easy to do with PCRE, BOOST or Dot-Net regex engines. Php uses PCRE so that'd be your best bet. I could give you a regex in 1 minute to do this if you decide to stray from JS

Comment: Can you explain the larger context? Why do you need these `span` tags to be replaced with `div` tags? This sounds like a [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use a regex to analyse/parse an HTML string. Instead use a DOM parser. You can use [`DOMParser`](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=domparser+mdn&ia=web) and do this:

```js
function replaceWithDivs(html, selector) {
    const doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(html, "text/html");
    for (const elem of doc.querySelectorAll(selector)) {
        const div = doc.createElement("div"); // Create the new element
        div.innerHTML = elem.innerHTML;       // Copy the contents
        elem.replaceWith(div);                // And replace old with new
    }
    return doc.body.innerHTML;
}

// demo
let html = `<span class="line"><span>// Before</span></span> 
<span class="line">
  <span>import</span>
<span> </span><span>db</span>
<span> </span><span>from</span><span>    </span>
  <span>'../../lib/db-admin'</span><span>;</span>
</span> 
<span class="line"><span>// After</span></span> 
<span class="line"><span>import</span>
<span> </span><span>db</span><span> </span>
<span>from</span><span> </span>
<span>'lib/db-admin'</span><span>;</span></span>`;

html = replaceWithDivs(html, "span.line");
console.log(html);
```